# JiBX : How to specify precision for Bigdecimal

Tags: xml, jibx

Im using Jibx to write my own binding for my java objects. Below is the block from my binding xml for a bigdecimal field.

```
....
<structure field="testVO">
<value name="joiningBonus" field="joiningBonus"/>
</structure>
....
```

On Marshalling im getting the Bigdecimal value with more decimal values. Below is the block of the output xml.

```
....
<joiningBonus>12345.45639999999912106432020664215087890625</joiningBonus> 
....
```

If i want Bigdecimal(21,6) precision, how to achieve it??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks none replied, it paved way to solve it by myself,

JiBX has functionality of serilizing and deserializing the values.

Below is part of my binding xml

```
<format label="decimalFormat" type="java.math.BigDecimal"
            serializer="com.test.Formatter.serializeBigDecimal" />
```

This is the format specifier tag, 
Formatter.serializeBigdecimal is the static method in public class which will be called on usage of format like below

```
<value name="joiningBonus" field="joiningBonus" format="decimalFormat"/>
```

Below is the public class and static method

```
public class Formatter{

    public static String serializeBigDecimal(BigDecimal joiningBonus) {
        return joiningBonus.setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString();
    }
}
```

Below is the before usage of serializer and after its usage output

Before:

```
......
<joiningBonus>12345.3467570000054754674578454567<joiningBonus>
......
```

After:

```
......
<joiningBonus>12345.346757<joiningBonus>
......
```